# How to load .so when using Robolectric?

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

W/Environment: EXTERNAL_STORAGE undefined; falling back to default

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.autonavi.amap.mapcore.MapCore.nativeNewInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at com.autonavi.amap.mapcore.MapCore.nativeNewInstance(Native Method)
    at com.autonavi.amap.mapcore.MapCore.<init>(MapCore.java:62)
    at com.amap.api.mapcore.AMapDelegateImpGLSurfaceView.<init>(AMapDelegateImpGLSurfaceView.java:356)
    at com.amap.api.mapcore.AMapDelegateImpGLSurfaceView.<init>(AMapDelegateImpGLSurfaceView.java:318)
    at com.amap.api.mapcore.ak.a(MapFragmentDelegateImp.java:123)
    at com.amap.api.maps.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:131)
    at com.e.activity.DriverReleaseActivity.initData(DriverReleaseActivity.java:179)
    at com.e.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at com.enjoytech.ecar.carpooling.activity.DriverReleaseAcitivityTest.init(DriverReleaseAcitivityTest.java:87)
    at com.enjoytech.ecar.carpooling.activity.DriverReleaseAcitivityTest.test(DriverReleaseAcitivityTest.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

It couldn't load the .so file.

When I use

```
try {      
    System.loadLibrary("libamapv304");
    System.loadLibrary("libamapv304ex");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it cause `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libamapv304 in java.library.path`

How can I using `.so` to complete unit test with Roboletric?

Comment: Do you set `-Djava.library.path` when launching your program? Ensure it points to a path that contains your `.so` dependencies.

Comment: I have done.But it also make an error ,.It said it need a .dll file

Comment: If you are using `.so` libraries, but the error complains about a not found `dll` then I guess you are using libraries compiled for linux. Try to find or compile that libraries for windows and place it into `java.library.path` path.

Comment: It it hard to recompile it for window because the .so file was offered by other company.

Comment: Can I work the same with Robolectric in linux?

Comment: I would not load so in Robolectric tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would load native libraries in some controlled way. For simplicity let assume it is in `Application`:

```
public class NativeLibApplication extends Application {
    ...
    protected void loadNativeLibraries() {
        try {      
            System.loadLibrary("libamapv304");
            System.loadLibrary("libamapv304ex");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Robolectric** gives you a possibility to tweak your application under the test. You should create `TestNativeLibApplication` in the same package under test folder and suppress loading native libraries:

```
public class TestNativeLibApplication extends NativeLibApplication {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void loadNativeLibraries() {
        //do nothing
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me.. :( What could be the reason. I am using realm database and roboelectric for unit testing

Comment: I have asked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413971/error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-roboelectric-and-realm?noredirect=1#comment71975589_42413971 please have a look

Answer (score 0):

## Support libraries that package native libraries

### Summary

**1. Disable load so in your app code.**

**2. Porting Dynamic Link Library.**

- If you use the Linux operating system that is the most simple, just get the `x86-64(Depending on your cpu architecture)` 's so file, and add the dependency so library(Found in the ndk-bundle, platforms folder).
- If you use the masOS operating system, you need to do a little more work. And you should have the native so library source code, and compile it under macOS system:

``` Bash

.o

cc -c -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers *.cpp

get  xxx.dylib

g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace *.o -o something.dylib

```

- Windows is similar.

**3. Load so library in your RobolectricApplication.**

End, run your test case, well done:

[load so test case http://rocko-blog.qiniudn.com/2016-11-27_09-32-15_test_case_success.png](http://rocko-blog.qiniudn.com/2016-11-27_09-32-15_test_case_success.png)

### Detail

Sample code: [RobolectricSupportNativeLibs](https://github.com/zhengxiaopeng/RobolectricSupportNativeLibs)