# Error : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with roboelectric and realm

Tags: java, android, realm, robolectric

Hi I am using `realm` database for my application and using `roboelectric` unit testing framework for performing unit testing. I see `realm` is written in native c code, it has `librealm-jni.so` file for their functionality.

I am getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError` error, read somewhere that robolectric does not support native libraries. I believe that there must be some way to resolve it. I tried accepted answer of this [How to load .so when using Robolectric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554998/how-to-load-so-when-using-robolectric) but no luck.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\XS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\android-tmp-robolectric7796034244909642596\app_lib\realm-jni.dll.2.3.1
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.SystemLibraryLoader.loadPath(SystemLibraryLoader.java:29)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibraryInternal(ReLinkerInstance.java:198)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibrary(ReLinkerInstance.java:136)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:70)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:57)
    at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:59)
    at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:187)
    at com.xyz.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication.onCreate(HelloWorldApplication.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:329)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:259)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> HelloWorldApplication.java

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("book.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }

    protected void loadNativeLibraries() {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("librealm-jni");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        }
    }
}
```

> TestHelloWorldApplication.java

```
public class TestHelloWorldApplication extends HelloWorldApplication  {

    @Override
    protected void loadNativeLibraries() {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work because Realm itself loads native libraries. So you need to move Realm initialisation in a method that will be not called or better mock it. Look for approach to https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/org/glucosio/android/GlucosioApplication.java

Comment: @EugenMartynov It is not going to work as I am calling `realm` methods in `oncreate` my activity, conceptually it will not allow me to call before initiating`realm` DB

Comment: My message was - It is good to abstract you storage layer from presentation layer

Comment: Thanks @EugenMartynov

Comment: You know you're not going to be able to load a .so on Windows right?  Does  your DB have a Windows .dll build?

Comment: @JJF It is not related to the OS on which you are developing application.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the roboelectric thing very well but it seems to me if the JVM is a windows JVM there is no way it's going to load an .so.  I'll butt out :-)

Comment: Maybe try this solution? Roboelectric with PowerMock: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleRealmTest.java

Answer (score 2):

Check this [out](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/904)

It is an open issue that Realm doesn't support Robolectric (yet).